# How can I prevent my API from being accessed by anything but my website?

Tags: java, javascript, api, web-services, react

I've got an API (Java + Play Framework). I've got a website (React) who has to communicate with the API. I don't want my API being called by anything but my website.

How can I do?

Comment: Just a related side note: How do you pretend to apply automated unit and integration testing of your API?

Comment: My API is unit tested thanks to an helper from Play Framework: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaTest#Unit-testing-controllers.

Comment: By that's not the question, in fact my API is called by multiple internal resources, it just doesn't have to be exposed for theses purposes. I don't want that someone be able to call my API exept my clients (for the moment only my website).

Comment: **Authenticate your requests.** The purpose of authentication/authorization is to limit users of your API to those people or computing resources that you have authorized.  Authentication means that anyone or any machine who cannot get authenticated will not be able to use your API.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that because I wanted my question to be simple: a user of my website has to be able to create an account and to log in. All my web services need authentication but these two can't. Once a user is authenticated, he receives a token (stored in a cookie) who's sent inside an header to authenticate every request. Then any informed user can get his token back, call my API with a curl for example and stole all my data. This is why I need that my API cannot be accessed by something else than my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

If it is available on the public internet, then anyone can call on that service.

If you need the public to use your application, then some part of it must be on the public internet, and you need **authentication**.

That's just how the internet works.

And that's also why Distributed Denial of Service Attacks work.

Your only defense against that is to deploy your application to a cloud computing network so a DDOS attack is hitting multiple server farms in multiple geographic locations, which reduces service outages to a geographic area, or just kind of slows things down since the distributed attack is perpetrated against a distributed application.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I always thought it was possible until I had to deploy my first public website!